# Copy files from one folder to another with desired names?

Tags: php, copy-paste

i am trying to copy files from one folder to another with desired names. For coping i used

```
copy($oldfile, $newfile);
```

one more thing old folder files should be deleted also.how can i rename them

Answer (score 1):

Use rename: Attempts to rename oldname to newname, moving it between directories if necessary. If newname exists, it will be overwritten.

```
rename($oldfile, $newfile);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: but i don't know the old file name

Comment: @user1702477 you must be joking...

Comment: @JimmyKane If only that were true...

Comment: i know the folder where files are uploaded its dynamically uploaded by users.so i dont know the files name.multiple images are uploading dynamically by jquery ..but i need to save the image with auto increment id .